# Enrolling MOK when installing VirtualBox 7 on 22.04

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 22.04, secure-boot

When I try to install `VirtualBox 7` on 22.04, it is asking to add `MOK` to the firmware while reboot. Is it safe to do so? I have an HP laptop with `Secure Boot` enabled.

Will it change the firmware permanently? I have dual boot Windows 10 on the same laptop.

Comment: VB won't work with SB on if you don't enroll a key. It won't change anything "permanently".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Virtualbox working you need to run a kernel module `vboxdrv`.

If you have Secure Boot enabled, the system won't let you run it without enrolling a key to UEFI.

You have to enroll it if you need to keep Secure Boot enabled.

It is quite safe and you can always remove keys from UEFI if you like.